# Why is the frame already changed when animation only started?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am learning CoreGraphics, more specifically affine transforms, and I have a test project. Simple custom view, containing a few geometric elements.(just to see that there is something.)

I have one viewController with root view and the custom view from above is VC's subview. The custom view frame has width of the screen and some height.

Here is the code.

```
__block CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2
                 animations:
                           ^{
                               transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(45));
                               self.customView.transform = transform;
                           }];
```

I don't understand why the view is already resized (it is shrinked horizontally and vertically) when I start to animate its rotation using affine transform. Shouldn't it start with view's original frame and resize it while it is rotating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between the actual view and what you see on the screen during the animation. Think of the animation as a "movie" that is projected in front of the real interface. Meanwhile, the actual view has already been changed. When the animation ends, the "movie" is removed, and there's the view sitting there identical to the last frame of the movie.

Comment: Might help you to read my book's discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_drawing_animation_and_threading

Comment: Yeah ehm it called presentation layer

Comment: @Andy That's right! And the fact that the presentation layer is different from the model layer is the reason why during the animation the OP _sees_ his view do one thing but _logs_ it as doing something else entirely.